# Saving data into Access database using VB 2010. Need full codes

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I created a database file using Microsoft Access for my application which I created using VB 2010. When installing on a different computer it displays the following error, related to saving the file.

> Unhandled exception has occurred in your application. If you click continue the application will ignore this error and attempt to continue. if you click Quit the application will close immediately.
>
> Operation must use an updatable query.

Error message details:

> `System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80004005)`: Operation must use an updateable query.

Can anyone explain how I can save to the database and prevent this error?

Comment: can we see the code causing the error?

Answer (score 0):

[This website](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/msoffice/when-access-queries-wont-update/578) gives a good summary of why an Access query may not be updateable. Without knowing more details about your particular situation, the best I can do is to copy the advice here and you can see if any of these apply to your situation. My initial guess would be that the database that doesn't work has been opened in read-only mode, or has a read-only flag set on the file, or that the user has insufficient permissions.

> The first step is to figure out why the query isn’t updateable. The
>   following queries aren’t updateable:
>
> - Any query with a GROUP BY clause.
> - Any query with a TRANSFORM clause.
> - Any query that uses an aggregate function (SUM(), MAX(), COUNT(), and so on) in the SELECT clause.
> - Any query that contains a DISTINCT predicate.
> - Any query that contains a UNION operator.
> - Any query that contains a subquery in the SELECT clause.
> - Any SQL Pass-Through query.
> - Any query based on three or more tables where there is a many-to-one-to-many relationship.
> - Any query that’s based on a read-only query.
>
> Sometimes a query that should be updateable isn’t. Usually, something
>   outside the query is the influence:
>
> - The underlying tables might be read-only. Or the database is opened in read-only mode.
> - The user must have permission to update the underlying data.
> - The record may be temporarily locked. Try again later.